# How can i access report's row count

Tags: c#, reporting, rdlc

I want to write rdlc's row count to on page. How can i do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This url will show you what you need to know: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159673.aspx#RetrievingRowCounts